# redirect subdomain traffic to my main domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have migrated my wordpress blog from https://blog.example.com to https://www.example.com/blog and everything is working fine.
Now my main concern is,google have indexed previous urls so how can i redirect my https://blog.example.com/post-name to https://www.example.com/blog/post-name.

Answer (score 0):

redirect the old ULRs archived by google with htaccess and google will know that you made that change.

```
# This will red`irect a subdomain to the main domain
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursubdomain\.yourdomain\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: how can i redirect something like this `https://blog.example.com/post-name` to `https://www.example.com/blog/post-name`